When can I unplug the Live-USB-Stick after trying Xubuntu 22.04LTS
After I shut down the system fro my Live-USB-stick with Xubuntu 22.04 LTS the screen shows in its middle "xubuntu" decorated with its logo. I don't know when the shutdown process is finished.
I would expect that the system either tells on the screen that shutdown has finished and the stick can safely be unplugged or it completely shuts and powers down the computer (if that's possible) leaving a black screen.
My USB stick (64 GB Intenso  Ultra Line Version 8.01) has a LED which lights up when the stick is mounted. Normally, the LED goes out when I eject the stick via Thunar. When I shut down the system booted from this stick, after some extended time, the LED also goes out.
I would like to know, if at least that's the time to safely disconnect the USB stick.

My belief is you're asking about a known issue, with details available in the bug report(s), ie.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/1944519
FYI:  The fix released refers to mention in Release Notes, and not a fix in the code.
I just booted a daily of Xubuntu jammy (22.04[.5]) and let it boot to the maybe-ubiquity TRY/INSTALL and select TRY, let it complete a full boot and I'm at the Xfce desktop.
I then told the system to shutdown, and I see the Xubuntu plymouth logo...  On the system I'm doing this test on, I soon get a black screen with the cursor TOP left and then nothing...  I wait a little.
If I press  Ctrl+Alt+F1 I can see

"Please remove the installation media, then reboot."

THAT is the missing message; and clue that it's safe to shutdown, if you really need that message.
You can use other generic tests on a working GNU/Linux system to confirm the kernel has shutdown etc too.

I mentioned on the system I'm using as Quality Assurance testing showed some differences in response depending on hardware. The box I used in writing this answer is hp prodesk 400 g1 sff (i5-4570, 8gb, amd/ati cedar radeon hd 5000/6000/7350/8350)  which may/may-not appear in the many bug reports; being a box used in QA.  Your box may react slightly differently, but most are similar to this.

guiverc, thanks for your answer. The other bug is a bit different, it's about reboot. - When shutdown is on its way, the screen must not be black. Only when shutdown has finished, it might go completely black or leave a finished-message. The user should be able to decide when it is right to remove the usb stick, unplug power and so on. There must not be any guessing or doubt about that! I hope this will be fixed soon, because false decisions in connection with shutdown or power off can ruin the stick (especially in connection with persistence) or the disk of the computer.

I'm booting live systems regularly in QA, and I don't use shutdown for that reason.... My personal choice is to use REBOOT instead of shutdown, as I find it easier to detect my hardware (and I'm talking about ~25 boxes here, so boxes aren't always reacting the same!) rebooting than waiting and searching for that message...   As soon as I detect the machine is in a normal reboot cycle I hit the power-button and cause it to shutdown myself...   That's my preference (ie. hardware rebooting I consider easy to spot & look for that)
